# Проблема в реализации нахождения СДНФ и СКНФ на питоне (модули использовать нельзя)

Tags: python, логика

В общем ,таблица истинности получилась,а реализовать СДНФ и СКНФ не получается,где то ошибка,выводит только отчасти правильный ответ,в очень странном виде

```
print ("x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 End")
for x in 0,1:
    for y in 0,1:
        for z in 0,1:
            __1 = x or z
            __2 = y == z
            __3 = __1 and __2
            __4 = z and y
            __5 = __3 or __4
            __6 = (z<= y)
            __7 = x and y
            __8 = __6 or __7
            End= (x or z) and ((y==z) or (z and y)) == ((z<=y) or (x and y))
            __1=int(__1);__2=int(__2);__3=int(__3);__4=int(__4); __5=int(__5); __6=int(__6);
            __7=int(__7); __8=int(__8); End=int(End);
            print(x,y,z, __1,__2,__3,__4, __5, __6, __7, __8, End);
n = 0 
#Находим СДНФ 
print("\nСДНФ: ", end="")
for x in 0, 1:
    for y in 0, 1:
        for z in 0, 1:
            
            if ( (x or z) and (((y==z) or (z and y)) == ((z<=y) or (x and y))) ) == 1:
                n += 1
            if n > 1:
                print(" V ", end="")
            if x == 1:
                print("x ", end="")
            elif x == 0:
                print("¬x ", end="")
            if y == 1:
                print("y ", end="")
            elif y == 0:
                print("¬y ", end="")
            if z == 1:
                print("z", end="")
            elif z == 0:
                print("¬z", end="")
#Находим СКНФ
n = 0
print("\nСКНФ: ", end="")
for x in 0, 1:
    for y in 0, 1:
        for z in 0, 1:
            
            if ((x or z) and ((y==z) or (z and y)) == ((z<=y) or (x and y))) == 0:
                n += 1
            if n > 1:
                print(" ^ ", end="")
            if x == 0:
                print("(xV", end="")
            elif x == 1:
                print("(¬xV", end="")
            if y == 0:
                print("yV", end="")
            elif y == 1:
                print("¬yV", end="")
            if z == 0:
                print("z)", end="")
            elif z == 1:
                print("¬z)", end="")
print("\nКонец программы")
```

Пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что означают эти аббревиатуры?

Comment: @Эникейщик  совершенно дизъюнктивная нормальная форма  и совершенно конъюнктивная нормальная форма